# Eloquent ORM with Laravel

Tags: php, orm, laravel, eloquent

I'm new in laravel world and I have one question. I didnt find answer in documents or google, so guys, please help me.

What is ORM equivalent for those SQL queries:

```
 SELECT email FROM users WHERE username=test
```

and

```
 UPDATE users SET email=test@domain.com WHERE username=test
```

Do I need to write specific function in my User model class or I can do those queries only with object of User model class?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will be like this:

```
$user = User::where('username','test')->first();
```

And to update:

```
$user = User::where('username','test')->first();
$user->email = 'test@domain.com';
$user->save();
```

Comment: or to update in one line:  User::where('username','test')->first()->update(array('email' => 'test@domain.com'));

Comment: Note that this is equivalent to `select * from users`, rather than `select email from users`. This is typical of an ORM, which follow a Active Record design pattern and assumes you want a database row to relate to a business logic entity (a users, in this case). If you truly want to select just the `email` field, you may want to use the Query object, which is not an ORM but simply a tool for querying the database.

Answer (score 2):

There are some ways to do what you want, feel free to choose which is more useful for you.

**With method-chainig**

```
// For "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username=test"
$email = User::where('username', 'test')->pluck('email');

// For "UPDATE users SET email=test@domain.com WHERE username=test"
User::where('username', 'test')->update( array( 'email'=>'test@domain.com' ) );
```

**With objects**

```
// For "SELECT email FROM users WHERE username=test"
$user = User::where('username', 'test')->first(); // Can be also an existing Eloquent object
$email = $user->email;

// For "UPDATE users SET email=test@domain.com WHERE username=test"
$user = User::where('username', 'test')->first(); // Can be also an existing Eloquent object
$user->email = "test@domain.com";
$user->save();
```